# Can't access app deployed with docker and google cloud

Tags: python, linux, docker, google-cloud-platform

I currently have a Linux Debian VM set up through Google Cloud Platform. I have docker installed and would like to start running application containers within it.

I'm following the documentation under Docker's website [Found Here](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/) under 
"Running a web application in Docker" I download the image and run it with no issue. I then run `$sudo docker ps` and get the port which is 0.0.0.0:32768->5000/tcp

I then try to browse to the website at http://"MyExternalVMIP":32768 but the applications doesn't come up. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your VM firewalled? What happens if you run `wget` or `curl` to that address *from the VM command line* as opposed to a different machine?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I'm pretty new to VMs and all that I'm a software guy. I'm ssh into my vm when I run all my docker commands. Do i just enter `wget` or `curl` in the VM shell by itself? `wget` alone returns `wget: missing URL` and some usage stuff. `curl` alone returns `Try 'wget --help' for more options`

Comment: Well you have to give it the URL.  wget or curl is basically a screenless web "browser" that dumps output to a file.  It is often used by software guys to test their webapps.

Comment: `curl http://localhost:32766` returns Hello World! Which is good.

Comment: OK if you use the IP number instead of localhost what does it do at the VM? From outside?

Comment: Well, thanks to your mention of firewall I did some fiddling on the VM side of things. I added a firewall rule for the port and boom. Thank you for the help @Paul

Comment: Good.  You can either delete this question or answer it yourself, with an outline of what you did to diagnose and fix it.  That might help others and add to your points.

Answer (score 3):

First, test to see if your service works at all. To do this, from the VM itself, run:

```
wget http://localhost:32768
```

or

```
curl http://localhost:32768
```

If that works, that means the service is operating properly, so let's move further with the debugging.

There may be two firewalls that are blocking external access to your docker process:

1. the VM's OS firewall
2. Google Compute Engine firewall

You can see if you're affected by the first issue by accessing the URL from the VM itself and from another VM on the same GCE network (use the VM name in the URL, not the external IP):

```
wget http://[vm-name]:32768
```

To fix the first issue, you would have to either open up [the single port](https://www.garron.me/en/bits/iptables-open-port-for-specific-ip.html) (recommended):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 32768 -j ACCEPT
```

or disable firewall entirely, e.g., by stopping iptables (not recommended).

If, after fixing this, you can access the URL from another host on the same GCE network, but still can't access it from outside of Google Compute Engine, you're affected by the second issue. To fix it, you will need to [open the port in the GCE firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#firewalls_1); this can also be done via the web UI in the [Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Create an entry in your local ssh config file as below with specific local forward port. In my case its an example of yarn's IP, which I want to access in browser.

```
Host hadoop
     HostName <External-IP>
     User <Local-machine-username>
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<private-key-for-above-user>
     LocalForward 8089 <Internal-IP>:8088
```